# apt-get update showing symbol lookup error

Tags: ubuntu-20.04, apt-get

I am running a vps server on ubuntu 20.04. After login to my server when i run `sudo apt-get update`, i am getting following error:

```
apt-get: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: undefined symbol: _ZNKSt10lock_error4whatEv, version GLIBCXX_3.4.11
```

I've looked for solution online, but most of them seems too old and i cannot run random commands, because its a live server and an application is running on production.
How do i solve this?